# MultipleObjectsReturned and ContentType

Tags: django, django-views, django-contenttypes

There is a function:

```
def Add_tag(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        if request.method == 'POST':
            form = TagsForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            # Get value
            item_id = form.cleaned_data['item_id']
            text = form.cleaned_data['text']
            user = request.user
            model_type = ContentType.objects.get(app_label='tags', model='Tag')

            # Get or create user rating
            try:
                obj_t = Tag.objects.get(user_id=user.id, content_type_id=model_type.id, object_id=item_id)
            except ObjectDoesNotExist:
                obj_t = Tag.objects.create(user_id=user.id, content_type_id=model_type.id, object_id=item_id)

            obj_t.text = text
            obj_t.save()

            return HttpResponse(status=200)
```

Model

```
class Tag(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    text = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, verbose_name=_('name'))
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    content_object = generic.GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return '%s %s' % self.user
```

The function should create only one object. In the first call, he created; the second - updated ... the third (or 4/5/6/7 .. 88/99/100 .. random) (the same values) is created again.

Why it is created?

MySQL, Django 1,5

Answer (score 0):

What I meant was you cannot use get because there are multiple records in your database

get expects to retrieve only one record/ object for multiple records there is filter on queryset

I don't understand why are you doing this but in your case you will have to also catch multipleobject returned exception

or use filter

```
objs = Tag.objects.filter(user_id=user.id, content_type_id=model_type.id, object_id=item_id).update(text=text)
```

Comment: The function should create only one object. In the first call, he created the second - updated ... the third (cover those most value) is created again. Why it is created?

Comment: @Silent because you are creating them

Comment: What?

First call: value (user_id=1, content_type_id=2, object_id=1) - create;
Second call: value (user_id=1, content_type_id=2, object_id=1) - update;
Third  call: value (user_id=1, content_type_id=2, object_id=1) - again create ...;

Comment: @Silent I am just saying there are multiple records for same user_id in your table. You should probably enforce unique constraint in your Model if this was not what you wanted

Comment: I know that. I do not understand why the object is re-created (with the third call) when it already exists in the database.

Comment: @Silent there is no field user_id in your model

Comment: @Silent why are you not getting field error in the first place

Comment: @Silent did you mean to write user__id in all your get queries?

Comment: @Silent No it does not for related objects you will have to use double underscore user__id and content_type__id while retrieving the objects